# How to host WCF services locally instead of http binding..?

Tags: wcf

How to host WCF services locally instead of http binding.. I mean the services should be hosted within the .NET environment and not by using http or netTCP.. Could you please help me with the configuration for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve here that can't be performed by using http or tcp settings for the local machine for both ends of the WCF contract? WCF isn't just between machines, you can also set it to communicate between different processes on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing between hosting a WCF service and a WCF binding. A WCF service can be hosted in many different applications such as standalone executables, windows services, a web server such as IIS, ...

Once you've found an appropriate host for the service you have to decide what binding to use. A binding is used to specify the transport, encoding, and protocol details required for clients and services to communicate with each other.

Note that choosing a host could further limit the choice of bindings available. For example if you decide to host your service in IIS you could only use HTTP/S as transport and NetTcp is not available (in IIS7 it is available through WAS).

Comment: Ya sorry for the confusion.. My requirement is that in the configuration we are using http or netTCp for binding .. is it not possible to bind within the local .NET environment without using the transport protocols..

Answer (score 0):

How to confgiure [NetNamedPipeBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx).

[How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx).